# Master-Detail Read Only

Tags: master-detail

When adding a detail record via the related list on the master record, the Master Record name appears on the page and can only be 'editable'.  Can this field be 'Read Only' or somehow retain the original entry?

Comment: On create, or during edit?

Comment: did you define the detail object as re-parentable?

Comment: SFDCFox - On create.  After it's created, the field is read-only.

Comment: Cropredy - I did not define it as re-parentable.  I just visited the object definition and can't see the option to do so.  What would that do?